# Showing multiple Context menu in WPF grid row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I wish to have two context menu in grid view in my WPf based desktop application .
Currently i am able to display one context menu, but I want to show context menu 1 on one condition and context menu 2 on another condition . How to do that?

I am usign following XAML code to show grid and context menu

```
<dg:UCGrid x:Name="grdLetVariables" Grid.Row="2" GridTypeSource="LetGrid"
                                                 DataContext="{Binding}" >
                                <dg:UCGrid.Resources>
                                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Object}" x:Key="GridExtensions">
                                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="ContextMenuDelete">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <Image Height="10" Source="../images/Delete.png"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <Separator />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Move Up" Click="MoveUpLetGrdRow">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <Image Height="14" Source="../images/UpMove.png"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Move Down" Click="MoveDownLetGrdRow">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <Image Height="14" Source="../images/DownMove.png"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <Separator />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Cancel" Click="CancelLetGrdRowEdit"/>
                                    </x:Array>
                                </dg:UCGrid.Resources>
                                <dg:UCGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                                            <CompositeCollection>
                                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource GridExtensions}" />
                                            </CompositeCollection>
                                        </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </dg:UCGrid.ContextMenu>
                            </dg:UCGrid>
                        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

Triggers on DataGrid can help you here. Code below is just for illustration ...

```
<UserContorl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="Condition1ContextMenu" ../>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="Condition2ContextMenu" ../>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:UCGrid}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition1}" Value="Value1">
          <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Condition1ContextMenu}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition2}" Value="Value2">
          <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Condition2ContextMenu}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Ofcourse condition1 and condition2 must be exclusive of each other. If both of them are applicable on the data grid then due to order `Condition2ContextMenu` will take the precedence.

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: I have a similar problem.. except that the data bindings for those ContextMenus don't work when I click on the menu items.  Any idea what is going on?